# Why this code is giving two different outputs for same input?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

For input(12134),in some cases it is giving output:"Yes" and in some cases it is giving "No".

```
package nagarroBootcamp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddEven {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int carnum = 0;
        int lastDigit = 0;
        int sumOfEven = 0;
        int sumOfOdd = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            carnum = sc.nextInt();
            int temp = carnum;
            while (temp > 0) {
                lastDigit = temp % 10;
                if (lastDigit % 2 == 0) {
                    sumOfEven += lastDigit;
                } else {
                    sumOfOdd += lastDigit;
                }
                temp /= 10;
            }

            if (sumOfEven % 4 == 0 || sumOfOdd % 3 == 0)
                System.out.println("Yes");
            else
                System.out.println("No");

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is, that you are not resetting these variables for subsequent input, you just initialize them once at the beginning, so only the first result is actually relevant

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            int carnum = 0;
            int lastDigit = 0;
            int sumOfEven = 0;
            int sumOfOdd = 0;
            carnum = sc.nextInt();
            int temp = carnum;
            while (temp > 0) {
                lastDigit = temp % 10;
                if (lastDigit % 2 == 0) {
                    sumOfEven += lastDigit;
                } else {
                    sumOfOdd += lastDigit;
                }
                temp /= 10;
            }

            if (sumOfEven % 4 == 0 || sumOfOdd % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Upvoted. You could also provide a solution (put those inside the `for` loop) while you're at it.

Comment: You are right, i edited the answer, thanks